# Ajax GET: multiple data-specific calls, or fewer less specific calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm developing a web app using a `Node.js`/`express` backend and `MongoDB` as a database.

The below example is for an admin dashboard page where I will display cards with different information relating to the users on the site. I might want to show - on the sample page - for example:

1. The number of each type of user
2. The most common location for each user type
3. How many signups there are by month
4. Most popular job titles

I could do this all in one route, where I have a controller that performs all of these tasks, and bundles them as an object to a url that I can then pull data from using `ajax`. Or, I could split each task into its own route/controller, with a separate ajax call to each. What I'm trying to decide is **what are the best practices around making multiple ajax calls on a single page**.

---

Example:

I am building up a page where I will make an interactive table using [DataTables](https://datatables.net) for different types of user ( currently have two: `mentors` and `mentees`). This example requires just two data requests (one for each user type), but my final page will be more like 10.

For each user type, I am making an ajax get call for each user type, and building the table from the returned data:

**User type 1 - Mentees**

```
$.get('/admin/' + id + '/mentees')
    .done(data => {
        $('#menteeTable').DataTable( {
            data: data,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "username"},
                { "data": "status"}
            ]
        });
    })
```

**User type 2 - Mentors**

```
$.get('/admin/' + id + '/mentors')
    .done(data => {
        $('#mentorTable').DataTable( {
            data: data,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "username"},
                { "data": "position"}
            ]
        });
    })
```

This then requires two routes in my Node.js backend:

```
router.get("/admin/:id/mentors", getMentors);
router.get("/admin/:id/mentees", getMentees);
```

And two controllers, that are structured identically (but filter for differnt user types):

```
getMentees(req, res, next){
    console.log("Controller: getMentees");
    let query = { accountType: 'mentee', isAdmin: false };
    Profile.find(query)
        .lean()
        .then(users => {
            return res.json(users);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}
```

This works great. However, as I need to make multiple data requests I want to make sure that I'm building this the right way. I can see several options:

1. **Make individual ajax calls for each data type, and do any heavy lifting on the backend** (e.g. tally user types and return) - as above
2. **Make individual ajax calls for each data type, but do the heavy lifting on the frontend**. In the above example I could have just as easily filtered out `isAdmin` users on the `data` returned from my ajax call
3. **Make fewer ajax calls that request less refined data**. In the above example I could have made one call (requiring only one route/controller) for all users, and then filtered `data` on the frontend to build two tables

I would love some advice on which strategy is most efficient in terms of **time spent sourcing data**

---

**UPDATE**

To clarify the question, I could have achieved the same result as above using a controller setup something like this:

```
Profile.find(query)
    .lean()
    .then(users => {
        let mentors = [],
        mentees = []

        users.forEach(user => {
            if(user.accountType === 'mentee') {
                mentees.push(user);
            } else if (user.accountType === 'mentor') {
                mentors.push(user);
            }
        });
        return res.json({mentees, mentors});
    })
```

And then make one `ajax` call, and split the data accordingly. My question is: which is the preferred option?

Comment: it depends of your application if application  gets all data to client and never change it is preferred to cache data in client. If data is changed and needs only one type of users on active page - it is preferred to get data with one type from server. bounty is certainly good but without any feedback  from your side it is tricky thing to provide you something useful for  your solution.

Comment: @OlegBondarenko Thanks for the comment - see update. I'm obviously not explaining the situation well

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Option 1

IMO I wouldn't serve unprocessed data to the front-end, things can go wrong, you can reveal too much, it could take a lot for the unspecified client machine to process (could be a low power device with limited bandwidth and battery power for example), you want a smooth user experience, and javascript on the client churning out information from a mass of data would detract from that. I use the back-end for the processing (prepare the information how you need it), JS for retrieving and placing the information (AJAX) on the page and things like switching element states, and CSS for anything moving around (animations and transitions etc) as much as possible before resorting to JS. 
Also for the routes, my approach would be each distinct package of information (dataTable) has a route, so you're not overloading a method with too many purposes, keep it simple and maintainable. You can always abstract away anything that's identical and repeated often.

So to answer your question, I'd go with Option 1.
You could also offer a single 'page-load' endpoint, then if anything changes update the individual tables later using their distinct endpoints. This initial 'page-load' call could collate the information from the endpoints on the backend and serve as one package of data to populate all tables initially. One initial request with one lot of well-defined data, then the ability to update an individual table if the user requests it (or there is a push if you get into that).

Comment: This strikes me as the most complete and practical answer. However, what is your take on the points raised by @skazska that `"many ajax requests could slowdown ui there could be a limitation for amount of ajax requests getting done at same time (it is browser dependent an could be from 2 to 10)"`

Comment: I'd certainly suggest reducing the number of synchronous calls as much as possible. I stated that you could design it to retrieve a 'first load' of data for the page (so you can have AJAX endpoints for individual packages of data, AND, to load an entire page). 

That said, could you not actually build your initial page render WITH the data, that's one call to serve en entire page then, instead of at least 2, and use AJAX to UPDATE it only? That would mean no AJAX calls until the user actually wants something to change, instead of using it as a default way to serve all data to your pages.

Comment: I'm confused though - which part of this is synchronous? As I understand it both `ajax` and `nodejs` are asynchronous - is this not the case?

Answer (score 2):

It is really good question. First of all you should realize how your application will manage with received data. If it is huge amount of data that are not changed on fronend but with different views and whole data needs for these views  it might be cached into frontend (like user settings data - application always reads it but rare changes)  then you could follow with *your second options*. Other case if frontend works only with small part of huge amount of database data (like log data for specific user) it is preferably  to preprocess (filtering) on server side *your first and third options*. Actually second options is preferable only for caching unchanged  data on frontend as for me.

**After clarifying the question** you could use grouping for your request and lodash library:

```
Profile.find(query)
    .lean()
    .then(users => {
        let result = [];    

       result = _(users)
        .groupBy((elem) => elem.accountType)
        .map((vals, key) => ({accountType: key, users: vals}))
        .value(); 
        });
        return res.json(result);
    });
```

Certainly you could map your data as you comfortable. This way allows to get all types of accounts (not only 'mentee' and 'mentor')

Comment: Actually there is  a lot of dependence of your project needs. If you try to avoid sending a lot of  requests to server side and creation dedicated controllers - you could use provided example with grouping. In case when this example becomes heavyweight or client side will use only one type of users insted whole data - you could always add additional api controllers to get refined data. My take-home message is create your application as *flexible* and *expandable* as it is possible based on your current requirements. Anyway You can't predict all cases using of your solution from the first time.

Comment: BTW: never try to use something like that let query = { accountType: req.params.userType}; Building your query to DB based on raw data from web request is direct way to unsecure code and malicious code injection. It might be not so crucial for no-sql  DB but it possible using  MongoDB commands inside  request params like { accountType : { “$gte”: “” } } and e.t.c..

Answer (score 2):

Usually there are 3 things in such architectures:

```
1. Client 
2. API Gateway
3. Micro services (Servers)
```

In your case :

```
1. Client is JS application code
2. API Gateway + Server is Nodejs/express (Dual responsibility)
```

**Point 1 to be noted**

Servers only provides core APIs. So this API for a server should be only a user api like:

```
/users?type={mentor/mentee/*}&limit=10&pageNo=8
```

i.e anyone can ask for all data or filtered data using type query string.

**Point 2 to be noted**

Since Web pages are composed of multiple data points and making call for every data point to the same server increases the round trip and makes the UX worse, API gateways are there. So in this case JS would not directly communicate with core server, it communicates with API Gateway with and APIs like:

```
/home
```

The above API internally calls below APIs and aggregates the data in a single json with mentor and mentee list

```
/users?type={mentor/mentee/*}&limit=10&pageNo=8
```

This API simply passes the call to core server with query attributes

*Now since in your code, API gateway and Core server is merged into single layer, this is how you should setup your code:*

```
getHome(req, res, next){
    console.log("Controller: /home");
    let queryMentees = { accountType: 'mentee', isAdmin: false };
    let queryMentors = { accountType: 'mentor', isAdmin: true };

    mentes  = getProfileData(queryMentees);
    mentors = getProfileData(queryMentors);
    return res.json({mentes,mentors});
}

getUsers(req, res, next){
    console.log("Controller: /users");
    let query = {accountType:request.query.type,isAdmin:request.query.isAdmin};
    return res.json(getProfileData(query));
}
```

**And a common ProfileService.js class with a function like:**

```
getProfileData(query){
  Profile.find(query)
        .lean()
        .then(users => {
            return users;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}
```

More info about API Gateway Pattern [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't estimate how many types need on your app then needs to be use parameters,
If I wrote like this application I don't write multiple function for calling ajax and don't write multiple route and controller,

Client side like this

```
let getQuery = (id,userType)=>{
$.get('/admin/' + id + '/userType/'+userType)
.done(data => {
    let dataTable = null;
    switch(userType){
        case "mentee":
        dataTable = $('#menteeTable');
        break;
        case "mentor":
        dataTable = $('#mentorTable');
        break;
        //.. you can add more selector for datatables but I wouldn't prefer this way you can generate "columns" property on server like "data" so meaning that you can just use one datatable object on client side
    }
    dataTable.DataTable( {
        data: data,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "username"},
            { "data": "status"}
        ]
    });
})
}
```

My prefer for client side

```
let getQuery = (id,userType)=>{
$.get('/admin/' + id + '/userType/'+userType)
.done(data => {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        data: data.rows,
        "columns": data.columns
        ]
    });
})
}
```

Server response should support {data: [{}...], columns:[{}....]} like this on this scenario [Datatables examples](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

Server side like this
Router just one

```
router.get("/admin/:id/userType/:userType", getQueryFromDB);
```

Controller

```
getQueryFromDB(req, res, next){

let query = { accountType: req.params.userType, isAdmin: false };
Profile.find(query)
    .lean()
    .then(users => {
        return res.json(users);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

So main meaning about your question for me that mentees, mentors etc... are parameters like as "id"

> make sure that your authentication checked which users have access userType data for both code samples mine and your code, someone can reach your data with just change routing

Have a nice weekend

Answer (score 1):

1. from performance and smoothness of ui on user device:
   Sure it would be better to do 1 ajax request for all core data (which is important to show as soon as possible), and possibly perform more requests for less priority data with some tiny delay. Or do 2 requests: one for 'fast' data and another for 'slow' (if this is applicable) because:

On one hand, many ajax requests could slowdown ui there could be a limitation for amount of ajax requests getting done at same time (it is browser dependent an could be from 2 to 10) so if for ex. in ie there will be limit of 2 then with 10 ajaxes there will be an queue of waiting ajax requests

But on the other hand if there is much data to show or some data takes longer to prepare it could result in long waiting for backend response to show something.

Talking of heavy lifting: It is not good to make such things on UI side anyway, because:
User device can be not good with resources and 'slow'.
Javascript is synchronous and as a consequence, any long loop 'freeze' UI for time it required to run that loop.

Talking of filtering users:

```
Profile.find(query)
    .lean()
    .then(users => {
        let mentors = [],
        mentees = []

        users.forEach(user => {
            if(user.accountType === 'mentee') {
                mentees.push(user);
            } else if (user.accountType === 'mentor') {
                mentors.push(user);
            }
        });
        return res.json({mentees, mentors});
    })
```

seems to have one problem, possibly query will have sortings and limits, if so final result will be inconsistent, it possibly end up with only mentees or only mentors, i think you should do 2 separate queries to data storage anyways

2. from project structuring, maintainability, flexibility, reusability, and so on, of course it is good to decouple things as much as possible.

So, finally, imagine you made: 
1. many microservices like for each widget 1 backend microcervice but there is a layer which allows to aggregate results to optimize traffic from UI in 1-2 ajax query.
2. many ui modules each working with own data, received from some service, which do 1-2 calls for aggregating backend and distributes different datasets it recieved to many frontend modules.

Comment: Like every other answer here, this appears to address some of my question, but I am left unsure of what you're **actually** saying. Would you be able to refine your take-home message?

Answer (score -1):

At back end just make one dynamic parametric method API. you can pass mentor, mentee,admin etc as role.you should have some type of user authentication and authorization to check if user a can see users in role B or not.
Regarding UI its up to user they want one page with drop-down filter or they want URLs to bookmark.
Like multiple url  /admin /mentor etc.
or one url with querystring and dropdown./user?role=mentor,/user?role=admin.
Based on url you have to make controllers. I generally prefer drop down and fetch data (by default all mentors might be the selection).
This is a specific invitation suited for invitations of a romantic nature (e.g. dates or engagement parties).